# Need to know precise steps for tattwa shuddhi sadhana?

Tags: rituals, tantra, sadhana, spirituality

As the title says I need to understand in brief precisely all the mandatory steps a sadhak needs to follow for tattwa shuddhi sadhana.

Please cite authentic references.

Comment: What is Tattva Suddhi Sadhana? Are you talking about Bhutasuddhi?

Comment: I think some people do refer to it as Bhutasuddhi though Bhutasuddhi maybe subset of the entire sadhana. @Rickross